# Filling values in to parent and child combobox from dataset in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have been trying to fill values into a parent and a child combobox, and when a user selects a value in a parent combo, a child combo value needs to be displayed based on the parent value.

This is the Form_Load code : (`MyDataSet.xsd` is the dataset name where `ITEM_HEAD` is the parent table and `ITEM_SUB_DETAIL` the child table)

```
 Dim ds As DataSet = MyDataSet

        Me.BindingSource1.DataSource = ds
        Me.BindingSource1.DataMember = "ITEM_HEAD"

        Me.BindingSource2.DataSource = Me.BindingSource1
        Me.BindingSource2.DataMember = "ITEM_SUB_DETAIL"


        Me.cboCategory.DataSource = Me.BindingSource1
        Me.cboCategory.DisplayMember = "ITEM_CATEGORY_NAME"
        Me.cboCategory.ValueMember = "ITEM_CATEGORY_ID"


        Me.cboItemCode.DisplayMember = "ITEM_SUB_NAME"
        Me.cboItemCode.ValueMember = "ITEM_SUB_ID"
        Me.cboItemCode.DataSource = Me.BindingSource2
        Me.cboItemCode.SelectedValue = Me.BindingSource1
```

While running, the code produces the following error :

> 'DataMember property 'ITEM_SUB_DETAIL' cannot be found on the
>   DataSource.

Where is the problem, and have any other best method to fill the parent and the child combo box?

Comment: you should load the child table also from `MyDataSet` instead loading from `Me.BindingSource1`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below,

```
Dim ds As DataSet = MyDataSet

Me.BindingSource1.DataSource = ds
Me.BindingSource1.DataMember = "ITEM_HEAD"

Me.BindingSource2.DataSource = ds
Me.BindingSource2.DataMember = "ITEM_SUB_DETAIL"
```

Because, you have to load the Child Table also from the master DataSet instead loading from another Table, as you pointed the `Me.BindingSource1` to a Table called `ITEM_HEAD` there's no chance to load another table from that BindingSource

Comment: Thank you very much Sai Kalyan Kumar, First combo works fine, but second is empty

Comment: @AmjadhNm, it seems there's no data in the ITEM_SUB_DETAIL table present in Master DataSet

Comment: no, its not empty, its having data as per norms of foreign key, is it because of any relationship issue ?